# Экспорт CSV из Bitrix

Tags: битрикс

Мне необходимо сделать выгрузку каталога в формате *CSV* с несколькими полями, в том числе *URL* данной страницы каталога. В стандартном сервисе выгрузки (Контент - Инфоблоки - Экспорт - CSV) поля *URL* нет.

Как добавить нужное поле в список выгружаемых полей?
Или есть еще какой-то способ получить *CSV* из *Bitrix*?

Answer (score 2):

Настоятельно рекомендую прочитать курс [Администратор.Бизнес](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/?COURSE_ID=42&LESSON_ID=3457&LESSON_PATH=3912.4580.4828.3457) в частности раздел про экспорт и импорт данных. Но 90% вопросов по 1С-Битрикс ответ есть в документации или на форуме.
Экспорт\Импорт инфоблоков работающих в режиме торгового каталога находится в административной панели в `Магазин > Настройки:`

- `Магазин > Настройки > Экспорт данных`
- `Магазин > Настройки > Импорт данных`

Answer (score 1):

CSV (а также другие типы) можно получить имея phpmyadmin

Возможно, для добавления строки с url-адресом элемента подойдет

```
arItem['DETAIL_PAGE_URL']
```

если он настроен и используется.

Можно добавить свойство инфоблоку с товаром и заполнять его при добавлении инфоблока.